# Get a href tag out of HTML

Tags: java, html, regex

I have the following code that gets the a href tags urls from an XML which is working correctly:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<a[^>]+href\\s*=\\s*['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"][^>]*>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(xmlString);
while (m.find())
    imagesURLs.add(m.group(1));
```

I have the following:

```
<a href="http://...">some text</a>
```

The top code gets me `<a href="http://...">` in `m.group(0)` and `http://...` in `m.group(1)`.

I also want to get the full `<a href="http://...">some text</a>`.

How can achieve this by modifying the regex?

Comment: Use a HTML parser instead

Comment: Can you explain why I want to do that? is it faster?

Comment: Because regex is brittle and unmaintainable (for this purpose)

Comment: Add another capturing group `(.*?)</a>` to the end and use with DOTALL [modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) , for making the `.` also match newlines (see [example](http://regex101.com/r/qM0vB8)). Using a [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) quantifier.

Comment: add it as an answer so I can appropriate it :)

Comment: [You can't parse HTML with Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: [Oh yes you can parse HTML with Patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/471272).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all the disclaimers about using regex to parse html: you can use this

```
(?is)(<a[^>]+href\s*=\s*(['"])([^'"]+)\2[^>]*>).*?</a>
```

1. Group 0 is the entire match: `<a href="http://...">some text</a>`
2. Group 1 is the opening tag: `<a href="http://...">`
3. Group 2 is something I added to ensure that your opening quote is the same kind as your closing quote. Ignore it.
   4 Group 3 is the url: `http://...`

See the groups in [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/dI4vA0)

To use in Java, as you know, you need to escape some characters. Something like:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?is)(<a[^>]+href\\s*=\\s*(['\"])([^'\"]+)\\2[^>]*>).*?</a>");
```

Comment: @hasan Did this solve it for you, or are you still wrestling with it?